# SwiftUI - Issue trying to display my drawermenu

Tags: ios, swiftui, mobile, rendering

I am trying to show a drawermenu when a user press on an image, but I'm facing an issue while trying to do that. When I tap on the image to display the drawermenu it only covers a small part of the screen, but I want it to cover the whole right side of the screen.
I have created my drawermenu in a separate file looking like this:

```
struct Drawermenu: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Settings")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(26)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}
```

And I am trying to display it depending on this variable:
 `@State var showMenu = false`
Which is set to true after the image is pressed:

```
 Image("drawermenu")
                .offset(y: -5)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showMenu.toggle()
                       
                }
```

And when showMenu is set to true, then this is how I display it:

```
.overlay(
            Group {
                if showMenu {
                    Drawermenu()
                }
            }
            )
```

I think that my problem is where, in my code, I tell it do display. However, I don't know where to put the last .overlay part of code, here is the code for my whole view:

```
Istruct HomeScreen: View {
    
    @State var showMenu = false
   
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.purple
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .frame(height: 50)
           
            HStack{
                TextField("Salong, område...", text: $userSearch)
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 20)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 35, bottom: 8, trailing: 16))
                    .fontWeight(.black)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13).fill(Color.white))
                    .offset(x: -14, y: -5)
                    .overlay(
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                .offset(x: -145, y: -4)
                        )
                
                Image("drawermenu")
                .offset(y: -5)
                .onTapGesture {
                    showMenu.toggle()
                       
                }
               
            }
            .overlay(
            Group {
                if showMenu {
                    Drawermenu()
                }
            }
            )
         
        } 
       
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
    
                HStack{
                // some code
                } .padding(.leading, -90)
                  
            
            Text("Stockholm, Sverige")
                
            Text("Senaste besökta")
            
            Text("Nawa Barbershop")
            
                HStack (spacing: 40){
                  // some code
                
                    .offset(y: -20)
                }
    
            
            Text("Salong Dröm Aura")
               
                HStack(spacing: 40){
                Text("Snurra ditt lyckohjul hos Salong Dröm Aura")
                    // some code
                
                Circle()
                   // some code
                    .overlay(
                    Text("10")
                       // some code
                       
                    )
                    .offset(x: 45, y: -30)
                
            }
          
                HStack{
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            // some code
                        Rectangle()
                            // some code
                            Image("crystalBarberShop")
                                .frame(width: 155, height: 86)
                            ) .cornerRadius(15)
                            .offset(y: -25)
                        Text("Crystal Barbershop")
                           
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                            
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                           
                        Text("7 km")
           }
                    
                        
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            // some code
                        Rectangle()
                           // some code
                        Text("Victor Noblesse")
                           
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                           
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                           
                        Text("7 km")
                            
                    }
                   
                }
                
                HStack{
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            // some code
                        Rectangle()
                            // some code
                        Text("Crystal Barbershop")
                            
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                           
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                            
                        Text("7 km")
                           
                    }
                   
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            // some code
                        Rectangle()
                            // some code
                        Text("Victor Noblesse")
                            
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                            
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                           
                        Text("7 km")
                           
                    }
                   
                }
                HStack{
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            
                        Rectangle()
                           
                        Text("Crystal Barbershop")
                            
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                                                  
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                            
                        Text("7 km")
                          
                    }
                   
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                           
                        Rectangle()
                           
                        Text("Victor Noblesse")
                           
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                            
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                         
                        Text("7 km")
                           
                    }
                  
                }
                
                HStack{
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.clear)
                          
                        Rectangle()
                            
                        Text("Crystal Barbershop")
                           
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                           
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                           
                        Text("7 km")
                            
                    }
                    
                    ZStack{
                        Rectangle()
                           
                        Rectangle()
                           
                        Text("Victor Noblesse")
                         
                      
                        Text("Scheelegatan 13 - Stockholm")
                        
                        Text("Snittpris: 370 kr")
                         
                        Text("7 km")
                         
                    }                 
                }
                
            } .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

I have tried to place this code:

```
 .overlay(
            Group {
                if showMenu {
                    Drawermenu()
                }
            }
            )
```

at other places in my code and I have also tried to remove my scrollview to see if it works without it even though I need the scrollview, but everything in my view just falls apart.
I have also tried to nest my whole code inside a ZStack but everything's just falls apart. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two main changes:

1. The body of your `HomeScreen` contains multiple top-level views/containers. I would suggest adding an outer `VStack` to define the layout for the body:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack { // <- ADDED
        ZStack{
            // content as before (until step 2 below)
        }
        VStack{
            // content as before
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

2. You can then apply the drawer menu as a trailing overlay to the outer `VStack`:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // see point 1 above
    }
    .overlay( // <- ADDED
        Group {
            if showMenu {
                Drawermenu()
            }
        },
        alignment: .trailing
    )
}
```

The syntax used here is the syntax for iOS 14, now deprecated. If you do not need to support iOS 14 then you should use `.overlay(alignment: .trailing) { /* content */ }` instead.

[image: Screenshot]

This should resolve the main issue of the question, but there may be other layout issues that still need resolving. In particular, I see that you are using offset to adjust the positions of various other views. I would suggest using padding instead.

Comment: I really appreciate this, thanks a lot. When you say I should use padding instead of offset, is it okay to then use .padding(.top 20) or for example padding(.leading -5 ) ??

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! You can use negative padding if you really need to, but if it is to negate the padding that is applied somewhere else then it would be better *not* to apply the other padding in the first place. Then you won't need to negate it. Sometimes this means moving the padding to a different container or view instead.